# how to test lock mechanism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a piece of code where I import a `BankAccountTransaction` to a `BankAccount`

```
 bank_account.with_lock do
   transactions.each do |transaction|
     import(bank_account, transaction)
   end
 end
```

it works fine but I need to write an RSpec case to it so I can be 100% sure I'm not importing transactions twice.

I wrote the following helper

```
module ConcurrencyHelper
  def make_concurrent_calls(function, concurrent_calls: 2)
    threads = Array.new(concurrent_calls) do
      thread = Thread.new { function.call }
      thread.abort_on_exception = true

      thread
    end

    threads.each(&:join)
  end
end
```

and I'm calling it on RSpec

```
context 'when importing the same transaction twice' do
  subject(:concurrent_calls) { make_concurrent_calls(operation) }

  let!(:operation) { -> { described_class.call(params) } }
  let(:filename) { 'single-transaction-response.xml' }

  it 'creates only one transaction' do
    expect { concurrent_calls }.to change(BankaccountTransaction, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

but nothing happens, the test suit gets stuck at this point and no errors are thrown or anything like that.

I've put a debug point (`byebug`) right after I instantiate the threads and tried to call the function and it runs fine but when I join the threads, nothing happens.

Things I tried so far

- breakpoint before `threads.each(&:join)` and call the function (works fine)
- breakpoint in the rspec example and debug `operation` and `params` (all good)

any more ideas?

**Edit**

this is my current DatabaseCleaner configuration

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end

  config.before do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  end

  config.before do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

I still haven't tried to modify the strategy to `:deleteion`, I will do it as well

Comment: Do you have RSpec configured to use transactional_fixtures? Or are you using some other clean up strategy/tool like DatabaseCleaner? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Comment: our `use_transactional_fixtures` is set to false and we are using DatabaseCleaner, yes

Comment: what strategy are you using with DatabaseCleaner? Have you tried the deletion strategy?

Comment: not yet, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: What version of Ruby and Rails are you running?

Answer (score 4):

`with_lock` is Rails's implementation which we don't need to test. You can use a [mock](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) and check if your code calls `with_lock`. The only trick here is to ensure the transaction gets imported (ie. the code inside `with_lock` gets executed). RSpec will provide the block which you can call. Below is a snippet of how you can do it - full working implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tejasbubane/897712413c38fd57a3c516c6fae8e13f).

```ruby
describe "#import_transactions" do
  it "runs with lock" do
    # Test if with_lock is getting called
    expect(subject).to receive(:with_lock) do |*_args, &block|
      # block is provided to with_lock method
      # execute the block and test if it creates transactions
      expect { block.call }
        .to change { BankAccountTransaction.count }.from(0).to(2)
    end

    ImportService.new.import_transactions(subject, transactions)
  end
end
```

Comment: this is quite nice, I haven't thought it this way but it solves *half* my issue. I still need to find a way to call `bank_account.with_lock` twice using two different threads, which I was unable to do so far

Comment: Exactly my point! That functionality is of Rails, not yours. You should not test library implementations - only test that your code uses the library in its intended way.

Comment: This is a beautiful spec. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a couple things going on here.

First, the heart of the issue likely lies in a couple areas:

1. **Database Cleaning Strategy**: You're using the [DatabaseCleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#supported-databases-libraries-and-strategies) which provide three cleaning strategies: Truncation, Transaction, and Deletion. My guess is that if you're using the `Transaction` strategy, the lock is never released because the first transaction is never committed and the second thread just waits for it to be released.
2. **Database Pool Config**: Another possible theory is that the connection pool for your test database is too small. This would mean that one (or both) of your threads are waiting to obtain a database connection. Typically there is a timeout configured for this and if one is set you should see an exception that looks something like this: `could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds`. To fix this, in your `database.yml` under `test` adjust your [`pool` setting](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling). You can inspect the values that are set by looking at:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.size
=> 5
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.checkout_timeout
=> 5
```

Second, in the code you provided, unless `import` modifies the transactions or the bank account that it imports, it appears as if the `with_lock` will not actually prevent multiple uploads.. it will just ensure that they run sequentially.

You might need to do something like this:

```rb
 bank_account.with_lock do
   unimported_transactions.each do |transaction|
     import(bank_account, transaction)
     transaction.mark_as_imported!
   end
 end
```

Additionally, if import is making some sort of external request, you should be careful around partial failures and rollbacks. (the `with_lock` wraps all SQL queries within it in a database transaction, and if an exception is thrown it will all rollback on your database but not on the external service)

Comment: about point 1: I updated my question with my current configuration. about 1.2 I doubt it would be because of the pool, It doesn't work even when I run only this spec alone. I can try increase as well but I do think you are right on the database cleaning strategy. about your second point, `import` actually uses a `find_or_create_by` so it can be run twice, I just need them to run sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to stub out the active record object and negate the database cleaner completely. Something like this (roughly):

```
let(:bank_account) { double('bank_account') }

before do
  allow(sweeper).to receive(:each).and_return([bank_account])
  allow(bank_account).to receive(:with_lock).and_yield
end

it 'locks' do
  expect(bank_account).to receive(:with_lock)
  ImportService.new.import_transactions
end
```

Please note this code example is very rough.